# Hooks in TensorFlow and distributed training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have a training job with a hook that sets variables during training:

```
class MyHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
   ...
   def begin(self):
       self._assign_op = tf.assign(...)
       self._assign_placeholder = ...

   def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
       ...
       run_context.session.run(self._assign_op, feed_dict={self._assign_placeholder: ...})
```

Training happens as usual witn estimators:

```
my_model.train(..., hooks=[MyHook()])
```

Now I'm trying to understand what happens when if I move over to distributed training. Will the hook run on all machines? If I currently find the tensor that I'm assigning to inside my hook using `session.graph.get_tensor_by_name()`, then will this work or will the tensor have a different name on the different replicas?

In other words, what do I need to consider to make something like this work with multiple GPUs or multinode training?